# 500 Internal Server Error when accessing web service from c#

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have been stumped on this problem for quite some time now. I am trying to create a SOAP request based on the information from a WSDL file to send to a web service and retrieve a response. From what I've read online this should be a fairly straight forward process, and all tutorials and guides have been almost the same.

Code:

```
string message = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
            <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
                <soap:Body>
                    <GetQuote xmlns=""http://www.webservicex.net/"">       
                        <symbol>BB</symbol>        
                    </GetQuote>  
                </soap:Body>
            </soap:Envelope>";

        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(@"http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx");
        webRequest.Headers.Add(@"SOAPAction:http://www.webservicex.net/GetQuote");
        webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
        webRequest.Method = "POST";

        XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = new XmlDocument();
        soapEnvelopeXml.LoadXml(message);

        using (Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
        }

        using (WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(soapResult);
            }
        }
```

I must not be clear on how this all works, to my understanding the http request is sent to the web service that we specify in the WebRequest.Create() method along with some other information like the SOAPAction which im guessing is the actual method we want to invoke? In the body of the message the xml namespace is linked and the elements have access through that namespace (GetQuote, symbol). So to me everything sounds like it should flow. There must be something I am missing or doing incorrectly because I am getting an internal server error when I try to read the response.

I am trying to access a very basic web service from www.webservicex.com. The links are provided below.

Service Link: http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx

WSDL: http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?WSDL

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to your test data choice. In a small bit of testing I found that submitting BB returns an exception response, but submitting APL (Apple) properly returns a stock quote.  It looks like the api is just not very well designed and explodes when given a request for data it doesn't manage?

As a side note sometimes it returns the exception response for APL too. Looks like their API just might not be very well designed.

You can test this yourself by navigating to http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?op=GetQuote which gives you a interface that allows for test submissions.

Comment: This is exactly my confusion. I've used that interface and even used the code samples in there to structure my SOAP messages.

Answer (score 0):

First You need to Make Sure that your web service is running or not. You can access web service only when it is in running mode. If its not running first run it then access from your application ...

Comment: Generally speaking, a `500` doesn't indicate a service isn't running, a `503` does. A `500` means an error in the application (or maybe IIS itself).

Answer (score 0):

I tried below approach, it gave me a meaningful error on browser, which helped in resolution:

- Go to menu Tools/Internet Options in your IE.
- Click on the Advanced tab, uncheck "Show friendly HTTP error messages" option and click Ok.
- Try accessing your web page again. Now you will see much more meaningful error message which will help you to troubleshoot the problem